# Why are CockroachDB S3 backup commands giving me an invalid delimiter?

Tags: amazon-s3, cockroachdb

I'm using an AWS S3-compatible service for storing CockroachDB backups, but on recent versions the service has started giving me errors about the length of the file delimiter, even though I'm not passing a custom delimiter. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [compatibility issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/100123) with CockroachDB 22.2 and S3-like services such as those provided by MinIO, Alibaba and Tencent. AWS S3 doesn't validate the length of the delimiter being used, but its documentation claims it does, so many services are accidentally more strict than it is. The linked issue will track fixes. In the mean time, it may be necessary to [use a different filestore.](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/use-cloud-storage.html)